# Implementation of Dijkstra and Graphs in Java

Tags: java, graph, dijkstra

I have a matrix as an input representing a map, for which I have to return the shortest path from a point A to a point B.

I wanted to know how graphs are implemented in Java (if a "graph" class existed) and if the API provided anything regarding Dijkstra algorithm. Do we really need to implement it from scratch as I see in numerus websites ?

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html

EDIT :
I was asking that regarding one of the Amazon online code question :

[image]

As we can only use the offical Java library, I guess they want us the code the algorithm from scratch. Would you confirm ? Or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no `graph` class exists in Java. However, it could be a really simple thing to do: a graph is a list of nodes and edges. You can then have a list of nodes linked to other nodes (= which contains a list of edges).

Regarding your second question (`Do we really need to implement it from scratch as I see in numerus websites ?`), you can find libraries containing this algorithm for sure. The first library I think of is called [Hipster4J](https://www.hipster4j.org/). You can do a lot with it so have a look :)